# recurring `sendmail` process

Tags: macos

I have a recurring thread of `sendmail` starting up repeatedly. I am not certain that its actually connecting to anything, but could be a issue.

How would you figure out what is triggering this process?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

At some point, someone probably tried to use Mail.app to send mail, but didn't have it configured properly. This might be causing sendmail to keep trying to deliver that mail.

If you are at least somewhat comfortable using Terminal, you can try to figure it out.

First, type `man sendmail`. That will identify a number of tools you can use to figure things out.

Next, if you type `mailq`, it may show you mail that is "stuck" in the queue — or it may tell you `postqueue: fatal: Queue report unavailable - mail system is down`. If the latter, then I am probably wrong about how you got here, and you'll have to explore other things.

At the end of the sendmail man page (in the "SEE ALSO" section) are a number of other man pages you can look at. In particular, if `mailq` is not empty, you can try `sudo postfix abort` to promptly shut down the mail system.

Another place to explore is the Console.app command. Click on "Log Report" in the left pane, and look through the list for things that might be related to mail, like `com.apple.email.maild`.

The sendmail system is complicated, involving a half-dozen or more background processes. I'm sorry I am not able to give you specific help, as my machine is not doing this. But I've outlined the steps I'd take to figure it out — hope that is helpful!

Comment: macOS ships sendmail?  Or still ships postfix pretending to be sendmail?

Comment: As far as I know, it's postfix, which is supposed to be plug-compatible with sendmail. The sendmail(1) man page cites "AUTHOR(S) Wietse Venema," and he's the guy who wrote postfix. At least, I don't believe I ever installed postfix on my system.

Comment: @MarcWilson, yes macOS ships with sendmail. you can just type `man sendmail` to check that its installed.

Comment: @JanSteinman `sudo postfix abort` always returns with `postfix/postfix-script: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running`.

So it doesnt appear to be related. There is no mail pending `mailq` returns `Mail queue is empty`

Comment: @JanSteinman, could it related to something from `launchd`. how would you figure out what `plist` is responsible for this?

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan, I send mail from my Mac, using gmail's SMTP interface. I looked at all the plists in /System/Library/Launch* and /Library/Launch* and didn't see anything getting launched, nor did `ps` show me anything running. I basically went into those four directories and did `fgrep mail *` to see which ones had the string "mail" in them, and came up with nothing obvious.